# How to access classpath files in a spring-boot jar?

Tags: spring-boot, jar, classpath

I didn't manage to access any classpath files in my spring-boot jar.

I tried the following :

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("myResourceFile");
```

But when I tried to read it, I got the following message

```
it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/myjar.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/myResourceFile
```

I noticed the 2 exclamation marks. The first is to indicate the resource is inside a jar, but I don't know if the second one (after classes) is involved in my problem.

Thanks for your help.

I use spring-boot 1.4.5 and spring-* 4.3.7.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to load an image from classpath , you can use something like below:

```
new ClassPathResource("/static/img/logo.png");
```

Resource Path:

```
main -> resources -> static.img -> logo.png
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to read a classpath resource is by getting the resource as stream.

This might fix your issue:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myResourceFile");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Indeed I can read a file inside my executable spring-boot jar with `InputStream`. The problem is I only know the folder name, and I do not manage to list file inside my folder with `InputStream`. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you can list files inside a resource folder (as a rule of thumb, resource files should be static). If you want to do it anyway then you will need to create a separate fixed file that lists all the files in your resource directory.

Answer (score 0):

I host a **Spring Boot application in Docker** on my VPS. This code will work on a local system whilst developing in an IDE **as well as if the .JAR-file is wrapped in a Docker image**:

Example case:

I like to get a PDF. The PDf document is located at `static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF`.

1.) Wire the class `ResourceLoader`

```java
private final ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

public MyService(@Autowired ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
    this.resourceLoader = resourceLoader;
}
```

2.) Create a resource by `pathOfAttachment` (`String`)

```java
String pathOfAttachment = "classpath:static/docs/not-a-porn.PDF"
Resource resource = this.resourceLoader.getResource(pathOfAttachment);
```

`Resource` is an interface that extends `InputStreamSource` as you can see in the documentation:

`public interface Resource extends InputStreamSource`

Source: `org.springframework.core.io` [Link to documentation (click here)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html)

3.) Get file

```java
String fileName = resource.getFilename();
File file = resource.getFile();
```